# Email notifications when issues are opened in GitHub

Tags: git, github

I am managing a repo and I am the release manager. I wish to receive an email whenever someone has opened an issue ticket in GitHub.

I looked at the webhooks and services. I found the following:
https://help.github.com/articles/receiving-email-notifications-for-pushes-to-a-repository/

I tried the above and found that the email is triggered only when I make any changes/updates to the repository.

But when I open a ticket, it does not trigger any email.

Does anyone have any neat way to trigger email notifications when issues are opened?

Comment: Does [**this**](https://github.com/settings/notifications) not do what you want?

Comment: Thank you Biffen your's is the simplest and elegant solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browse to `https://github.com/{{your org/user}}/{{repository}}/settings/hooks/new` and you'll see that you can add a webhook to get notified when an Issue is created.

**EDIT: I forgot to mention one very important thing. You need to create a public web application that handles these requests! I.e., you need to add a webhook to this app. The code that handles this request can then do whatever you like, e.g. send an email.**

Screenshot from GitHub:

[image: Add webhook]

More info here: https://developer.github.com/webhooks/

Comment: Thanks a lot. What does the Payload URL mean in that page ?

Comment: It's the URL where GitHub will send you a POST request with the data. You need to handle this requests